# unstable / variating sound level (volume) within same song / clip

Tags: windows-7, audio, mp3

I have a pretty standard Acer desktop (I guess a predecessor of the X5900 model).

when playing mp3 / radio / youtube clips, the sound level is changing WITHIN the clip, highly annoying.

in the case of an mp3, the same mp3 will play at a constant sound level on my iPod, so clearly an issue with the computer.

problem existed under vista, I upgraded to windows 7 and have the same issue.

I guess it might be soundcard-related, so updated the drivers, no luck neither.

any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is solved.
I think it caused by kind of automatic/dynamic sound level contoller built in vista and in windows 7 (it is stronger in windows 7) and there is no button to disable it.

To solve this:

- try to disable the equalizer on windows media player or if it is not disabled, reduce its high frequency level.
- try to disable or adjust the sound card equalizer, if your sound card has its own equalizer.

I hople it works for you too. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing unstable sound output in my windows media player as told by others. This was a decade ago and I had involuntarily turned off the equalizer and the sound blasted crystal clear ! Recently after upgrading my HP dual core, ws 7 to 64 bit it reappeared and  I have done the same thing, it worked OK.Using the equlizer in other players like VLan,`player etc never posed this problem though. So use VLan or KM player instead !`